# Flutter: Add Authenticated Users to Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to authenticate newly registered users from a sign-up page and add them to my cloud-firestore database once they are authenticated. At the moment, the users are authenticated and the code works fine up to that stage. However, they are not added to the cloud-firestore database. Please help!

```
Container(
                    width: 150.0,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Sign Up'),
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_registerFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          if (pwdInputController.text ==
                              confirmPwdInputController.text) {
                            FirebaseAuth.instance
                                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                    email: emailInputController.text,
                                    password: pwdInputController.text)
                                .then((currentUser) => Firestore.instance
                                    .collection("users")
                                    .document(currentUser.user.uid)
                                    .setData({
                                      "uid": currentUser.user.uid,
                                      "first-name":
                                          firstNameInputController.text,
                                      "last-name":
                                          lastNameInputController.text,
                                      "email": emailInputController.text,
                                      'password': pwdInputController.text,
                                    })
                                    .then((result) => {
                                          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      MyApp()),
                                              (_) => false),
                                          firstNameInputController.clear(),
                                          lastNameInputController.clear(),
                                          emailInputController.clear(),
                                          pwdInputController.clear(),
                                          confirmPwdInputController.clear()
                                        })
                                    .catchError((err) => print(err)))
                                .catchError((err) => print(err));
                          } else {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text("Error"),
                                    content:
                                        Text("The passwords do not match"),
                                    actions: <Widget>[
                                      FlatButton(
                                        child: Text("Close"),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        },
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  );
                                });
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: do you have any logs printed on the console?

Comment: No, I don't. :-(

Comment: I also noticed that it does't redirect to the homepage - MyApp()

Comment: Print the result after the firestore insertion and see what is the return value

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil() above this code just add print(result);

Comment: I get an error: This expression has a type of void so it can't be used

Comment: I have seen some code out there which uses async and await to achieve a similar result. How can I refactor the code using that method?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HbBwhch1 checkout this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine on my emulator so I would double check the following make sure you have set up firestore properly [Documentation can be found here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) Also double check your security rules for your datatbase [Documentation for security rules can be found here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

if your database if still in testing phase your rules would look something like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 5, 5);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the security rules. I changed the 'if false' to 'if true'. But, it's still not working.